# IExecutorService submit runnable order

Tags: java, hazelcast

It seems that tasks submitted to executor chooses a random instance. Is there a way to make it choose only from available ones? For example, I have 10 hazelcast insances and I want my instances to be used by only one runnable at a time. If all are in use, the new comer has to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MemberSelector interface to implement load balancing but you can also calculate the member first and submit your job to a specific member or key owner. See IExecutorService interface.

Comment: Is there a way to limit one instance to be assigned maximum one task at a time? If yes, it will automatically do what I want. It will give the job to the free ones, if there is no available ones then it will be added to queue. Thanks

Comment: No sorry, there is actually nothing like this at all. You have to build those load balancers on your own. Like using an IMap for metadata and a the MemberSelector (or a custom thinggy) to submit tasks and prevent overloading.